# Captcha validation using Regex in python

Tags: python, regex, automation

hi am trying to validate a simple captcha in python using Regex

```
import re

captcha = "10 + 5"
numbers = re.findall('\d+', captcha)
num1 = int(numbers[0])
num2 = int(numbers[1])
sym = re.findall('\D+', captcha)
operator = sym[0]
# print(operator)
# captcha_answer = 0
if operator == "+":
    captcha_answer = num1 + num2
if operator == "-":
    captcha_answer = num1 - num2
if operator == "*":
    captcha_answer = num1 * num2
print("captcha_answer =", captcha_answer)
```

i needed answer 15 but i am getting a error saying 
"name 'captcha_answer' is not defined"
or if define a false value like 0 for captcha_answer the output is 0
how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`operator` is  `+`  (with blancs arround), so it doesn't match your if conditions. Removing the whitespaces makes your code work:

```
operator = sym[0].strip()
```

Output:

```
captcha_answer = 15
```